# In pytyon is it possible to prevent the text's pixel while removing lines in image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working in text extraction process inside the table.But while removing the table lines it affecting the text's pixel.is is possible to keep the text pixel which is overlays on the table line pixel.

**original image as RGB**
[image]

*this image is the cropped from original image for reference*

**output region**
[image]

Comment: Maybe if you had the RGB version of the input image, it may have been possible. But it would be hard to differentiate in case of binary images as we cannot perform color segmentation. One thing I would like suggest here is: Morphological Operation with custom kernel. Give it a shot.

Comment: @ZdaR ,can you be more specific in this question!!

Comment: @ZdaR: black and white printed documents obviously contain no color information !

Answer (score 1):

Use eroded (or dilated black objects) second image as mask for first image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#images need equal size
original=cv2.imread('RdfpD.png')
mask = cv2.imread('zxLX4.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,5))
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh,se,iterations = 1)
dilate=cv2.bitwise_not(dilate)
dilate=cv2.cvtColor(dilate, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out=cv2.max(dilate, original)
cv2.imwrite('out_5.png', out)
```

[image]